# Outputting base64 image data to new window without getting blocked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

Having a bit of a Javascript nightmare at the moment.

I'm using html2canvas to convert a div into a canvas then `.toDataURL` to convert the canvas into a base64 data stream.

I would like to have base64 image data open in a new window but it gets blocked by every popup blocker I've tested.

Here is a sample of my function

```
function generateImage(xarg){
    var divid= document.getElementById(xarg);
    html2canvas(divid, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(imgdata);
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea why my `window.open` is being blocked?

EDIT: Another idea I've had is to initiate a download of the image, but every solution I've found requires the data to be changed to `image/octet-stream` which messes up the filetype, and well my users won't be able to deal with that (especially those on mobile devices).
I originally had a much longer post explaining my circumstances but I truncated it in favour of brevity.

Comment: Is this happening in a `click` event? Or are you running this at some other time? Did you try replacing `imgdata` with `""` to see if it opens an empty window?

Comment: @Ian I have an `<a>` that calls the function in an `onClick` attribute. Just tried `window.open("");` and it's still being blocked. I know there's something I'm doing wrong here that's being flagged as malicious, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: I'm betting the `onrendered` method is an asynchronous one, so the scope loses its "clicked" context and therefore is blocked by a popup blocker (like other popups opened by `window.open` not by a `click` event)

Comment: It's not malicious, it's just because the method is asynchronous, that by the time it's executed, the browser doesn't know it was originally triggered by a `click` event (which is required in order to not be blocked)

Comment: @Ian Interesting, thanks for the insight, I'll try a few tricks.

Comment: Yeah, it's the browser's way of preventing a website from infinitely/uncontrollably generating popup windows without user interaction. So since you said this is called from a `click` event, I'd guess the problem is because `onrendered` is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Other direct responses about the popup being blocked because of the asynchronous way it is opened (even from a callback of a click event). I worked the issue around by:
 - opening a blank popup directly on the click handler
 - launching the "canva-ification" of the html content
 - creating a temporary form which posts the canva base64 data in the popup

The downside of this approach is that the user has a blank popup while the canva is generated. I hope this helps.

```
function clickHandler(elementId /*the id of the element to convert to an image */) {
    // opens the popup directly -> not blocked by browsers
    var popup = window.open('about:blank', 'screenshotWindow', 'width=950,height=635');

    // creates the form
    var form = window.document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('target', 'screenshotWindow');
    window.document.body.appendChild(form);

    html2canvas(window.document.getElementById(elementId), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // posts the base64 content in the popup with the form and removes it
            form.setAttribute('action', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            popup.focus();
            form.submit();
            window.document.body.removeChild(form);
        }
    });
}
```